# PC to iOS, USB storage Malware?

Tags: malware, virus, ios, usb-drive

I have a laptop, with Windows 7, no internet (with the wifi adapter physically removed). I want to use that machine for stuff like old abandonware, and don’t want to risk any type of malware or virus spreading (hence why it's offline).

I do need a way to download and load that abandonware and was thinking of using an iOS device with a USB key and USB adapter.

Could this lead to infecting my iOS device in any way? Can iOS get infected by a USB key?

I even have a separate iOS device just to do this, but still wondering what are the implications

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents, iOS can get infected but it is very hard.

You would need to give some run permissions to that malware in most cases, just like in most cases just downloading a zip with malware won't actually execute it on PC.
iOS ecosystem is built like a tank. iOS has the smallest number of malware and since malware is generally built to attack specific platform, it is really low possibility that your iOS could get infected. However, there is always a chance and you should count on it to get infected. There are cross platform viruses/scripts. Backup everything from iPhone, and do a factory reset if it gets sluggish or you see some unexpected behaviour. Also remove: personal images, passwords, bank account details, contacts and anything sensitive from the iPhone.

Also, you could run into compatibility problems with iOS/windows, when transffering files.

Last word, if you are searching for malware online, front end will detect iOS in browser and serve you iOS malware.